# BackgroundWorker returns to wrong thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, ui-thread

In my application, I create a new UI-Thread with the fallowing code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        MyWindow windowInAnotherThread = new MyWindow();
        windowInAnotherThread.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }) { IsBackground = true };
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
```

This give me the fallowing problem:

In the constructor of the MyWindow class, a BackgroundWorker is executed. In the RunWorkerCompleted there should a Control be updated with some data, which the BackgroundWorker is calculating.

I have build a small sample, which is illustrating this:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window {
    public MyWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        this.Title = "Calculated title";
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

In `bw_RunWorkerCompleted()` I get an `InvalidOperationException` (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.). It looks like, that the BackgroundWorker is not returning to the correct UI-Thread from which it was started from.

Can someone help me, what I can do to solve this problem? I can't change the Code which is executing the BackgroundWorker, because it is in a framework, which I use. But I can do something else in the RunWorkerCompleted-Event. But I have no idea, how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you "create a new UI-Thread" at all? Not necessary, not productive and the source of this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the window is getting created too soon.  The thread doesn't have a synchronization context yet.  You can see this is the debugger by setting a breakpoint on BGW constructor call and look at Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext.SynchronizationContext.  It's null.  Which is what BGW uses to decide how to marshal the RunWorkerCompleted event.  Which no synchronization context, the event runs on a threadpool thread and that invokes wrath.

You need to get the dispatcher initialized sooner.  Not 100% this is the correct way but it did seem to work:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                MyWindow windowInAnotherThread = new MyWindow();
                windowInAnotherThread.Show();
            }));
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

You also have to explicitly force the thread to shutdown.  Add this method to MyWindow:

```
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

Comment: Or delay creating the bgw, now that I think about it :)

Comment: You can't call BeginInvoke like this, as it's going to push the Window creation into the UI thread (Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is the current window's dispatcher, not the new thread one...)

Comment: I think this would work if you used `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I feared.  Better delete that.

Comment: I started writing this - then figured I should test it, which is how I came up with my version...  Just tried, if you use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke`, this approach works.

Comment: Hi Hans - this is working great - also in my productiv Application. Thank you very much. I have one more small question about this: Shouldn't my new UI-Thread be terminated, when I close MyWindow? Does I have to change something, that the thread will be terminated after closing the MyWindow?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into similar issue. Based on note 1 and 2 below  I created UIBackgroundWorker. May be it can help other developers who encounter this issue.

If it works then please let me know or update the design for benefit of other developers.

```
public class UIBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{

    private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher uiDispatcher;
    public SafeUIBackgroundWorker(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher uiDispatcher)
        : base()
    {
        if (uiDispatcher == null)
            throw new Exception("System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher instance required while creating UIBackgroundWorker");
        else
            this.uiDispatcher = uiDispatcher;
    }

    protected override void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (uiDispatcher.CheckAccess())
            base.OnProgressChanged(e);
        else
            uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => base.OnProgressChanged(e)));
    }

    protected override void OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (uiDispatcher.CheckAccess())
            base.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e);
        else
            uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => base.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to setup the `SynchronizationContext`.  This is normally not an issue, as `Dispatcher.Invoke` will set it up for you, but since you're using `BackgroundWorker` in the constructor (which is fired prior to `Dispatcher.Run`), no context is setup.

Change your thread creation to:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // Create the current dispatcher (done via CurrentDispatcher)
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        // Set the context
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(dispatcher));

        MyWindow windowInAnotherThread = new MyWindow();
        windowInAnotherThread.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

This will cause it to run correctly, as the `SynchronizationContext` will be in place prior to the construction of the Window.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a `getter` and `setter` for your `BackgroundWorker` inside `MyWindow`. And pass BackgroundWorker object via setter method to Mywindow. That should solve the problem, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegate method and an invoke in the calling function. There's a good example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Using your code,

```
    public partial class MyWindow : Window {


    delegate void TitleSetter(string title);

    public MyWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void SetTitle(string T)
    {
      this.Title = T;
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

      try    
        {
        TitleSetter T = new TitleSetter(SetTitle);
        invoke(T, new object[]{"Whatever the title should be"}); //This can fail horribly, need the try/catch logic.
        }catch (Exception){}
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. And in WPF it is `Dispatcher.Invoke()`

Answer (score 0):

I think simply moving your background worker thread setup code into the "Load" event instead of the constructor should be just fine.